# Active Record class

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am working on a migration project. Wanna migrate a rails 2.x app to 3.x. I have a problem with active record.

In Rails 2.x:

```
arr=StorageUnit.find(:all, :conditions =>"type='Drawer'")
```

The above code will get me all records with type Drawer.

```
arr.class
=> Array
```

In Rails 3.x:

Here the above function is deprecated. So i had to use

```
arr=StorageUnit.where("type='Drawer'")
```

The above code will get me all records with type Drawer.

```
arr.class
ActiveRecord::Relation
```

I guess this is because of the change in Active Record.
My problem  is i have some code based on this class.

For ex:

```
if arr.class== Array 
   do something
else
   do something
end
```

So as off now i have changed it to

```
if arr.class== ActiveRecord::Relation 
   do something
else
   do something
end
```

Just curious to know whether there is any better solution or any alternative way to solve it. I have a lot of place where they have used such stuff.

**EDIT:**

```
arr=StorageUnit.where("type='Drawer'").all
```

will provide the class as Array. My objective is to know when the code without suffix can provide you the required records than what is the use of all in the end.? Is it just to change class? Can anyone ecxplain?

Comment: Explicitly checking the class of things isn't very idiomatic ruby

Comment: @FrederickCheung is correct.  If you need to absolutely check the class, you can use `arr.is_a?(Array)`

Answer (score 2):

`StorageUnit.where` simply returns the `ActiveRecord` relation. Tacking on `.all` will execute the sql and create instances of `StorageUnit`.

```
arr = StorageUnit.where(:type => 'Drawer').all
```

There are many interesting side effects of it being returned as a relation.  Amongst other things, you can combine scopes before executing:

```
StorageUnit.where(:type => 'Drawer').where(:color => 'black')
```

you can view the resultant sql for debugging:

```
StorageUnit.where(:type => 'Drawer').to_sql
```

Imagine this:

```
class StorageUnit < ActiveRecord::Base

  scope :with_drawer, where(:type => 'Drawer')
  scope :with_color, lambda { |c| where(:color => c) }

end
```

Now:

```
StorageUnit.with_drawer.with_color('black').first_or_create # return the first storage unit with a black drawer
StorageUnit.with_drawer.with_color('black').all # return all storage units with black drawers
```

The relation allows for underlying query to be built up even saved for later use.  `all` and other modifiers like it have special meaning to the relation and trigger the database execution and building of model instances.

Comment: I know the class will be Array in this case but i have a question. When the code without all can get the required records than what is the use of specifying all. Both gives the same result rite..? But different class.

Comment: `with_drawer` doesn't need to be a lambda, just the `where(:type => 'Drawer')` without the lambda wrapper will do; `with_color` should be a class method because ["Using a class method is the preferred way to accept arguments for scopes"](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#passing-in-arguments). Just being picky :)

Comment: I had no idea Rails recommended class methods instead of scopes. Do you know why is it preferred over scopes, @muistooshort? They're virtually the same, I believe.

Comment: @AmarnathKrishnan `all` in Rails 3 and `to_a` in Rails 4 runs the query for you. Sometimes you want the query to be run in a specified time vs. when it is really needed.

Comment: @PedroNascimento: I'd guess that it is because the class methods (such as `where`) are there already so lambda aren't needed but that's just a wild guess.

Comment: @PedroNascimento It appears the reason is that scopes are not available against associations: SomeModel.some_scope (valid), another_model_instance.associated_some_models.some_scope (not valid).  But the class method is available through associations.  At least that is what the documentation states: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#passing-in-arguments

Comment: Scopes are valid through associations.

Comment: @PedroNascimento I thought that was true as well, but the documentation implies otherwise.  Is the documentation wrong? Or is my interpretation wrong?

Comment: I think your interpretation is wrong. It just says "it's fine using class methods as they will be available on associations anyway". I would guess class methods weren't available on associations before, but they're now-ish.

Comment: @PedroNascimento Yep, I think you're right.  Seems like a stylistic preference then.